# Is there a general Exception-class that takes an int besides the message?

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I need an `Exception` class that takes both a message and an `int` as parameters, and would rather use an existing one instead of creating my own custom derived Exception.

I've been searching for one, but it's proving more difficult than I thought.

Is there such a (generally named) class?

**EDIT**

I intend to catch it and display: `"Error " + ex.Message + ex.Code.ToString();`.

The error-code is for a **message** that I would rather not display to a user. (Technical stuff for debugging etc. The error **code** *will* be displayed so the user can tell me what code he got.)

My reason for preferring an existing Exception is that I want to have a uniform way of handling exceptions in all of my applications and not have to define them every time.

Comment: @Magnus An error-code for a message that I would rather not display to a user. (Technical stuff for debugging etc. The error _code_ _will_ be displayed.)

Comment: I'd make a new one, as if you can't find it it means that even if there might be one, it will probably not be suited for your purposes. And anyways, they all do: just stick it in the `HResult` property **(NOT RECOMMENDED)**

Comment: Creating a new one isn't complex and would be much more appropriate than finding an obscure Exception type taking an int IMO.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault My reason is that I want to have a uniform way of handling exceptions in all of my applications and not have to define them every time.

Comment: @ispiro I still think it would be better to define it everywhere than seeing for example a `throw new ObscureUnrelatedException(2);` in all your applications. If someone else have to go in them, they won't get why you're throwing that. You could build a class library for your general helper method/classes and put that there. Reference your dll in all your apps, so you won't have to change everything each time you want to modify your exception class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best thing, as already noted, is to create 1 or more special Exception classes for your Application Domain. A good design also includes provisions to break down gracefully.

But there is another route, the seldom used [`Data` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.data.aspx) of the base Exception class.

It is a Dictionary that allows you to add custom data to any exception. Useful when you intercept (catch and re-throw) exceptions and want to add some ambient information.

```
try 
{
    using (var reader = File.OpenText(fileName))
    { 
       ... 
    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
   e.Data.Add("Filename", fileName);
   throw;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Looking into `Data` now.

Answer (score 2):

There absolutely are existing exceptions that do this, but it would be wise to still define your own.

Since you want to pass in an integer value, I assume you want to catch that specific exception somewhere. If you don't have any specific handling for that exception, it would be useless to use a specific exception; you could use any normal exception such as `InvalidOperationException` where the value is part of the exception message.

So since you want to handle that exception specifically, reusing one of the existing exceptions is unwise, since the framework or other third party tools could throw those, making it hard to differentiate between the exceptions you thew and exceptions other threw.

Comment: Thanks. But, No, I wouldn't catch them other than to display: `"Error " + ex.Message + ex.Code.ToString();`

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of an exception is to report exceptional behaviour. Since an exception  is not expected it's name should be self descriptive. So not the property is important but the name of the exception.

So just create a new exception that has a meaningful name and add your `int` property.

```
public class InvalidNumberException : System.Exception
{
    public InvalidNumberException() : base() { }
    public InvalidNumberException(string message) : base(message) { }
    public InvalidNumberException(string message, int number) : this(message, null, number) { }
    public InvalidNumberException(string message, System.Exception inner) : base(message, inner) { }
    public InvalidNumberException(string message, System.Exception inner, int number) : base(message, inner)
    {
        this.Number = number;
    }
    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: As you said - This is for a exceptional behavior. The type that the application will _not_ try to solve but just print out the message plus the code. So I don't mind if it's called ProblemDetectedException or anything general.