# How to create your own exception

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

I'm specifically looking for a solution for a console app, however answers for form apps are also welcome.
Would you be so kind as to help me with the following problem?

**My Problem:** 
I want to create my own Exception that will catch any number from 5 to 9 when a user types one of them.

NOTE: I know I can solve this problem by simply playing with `IF ELSE` statements but I'm specifically looking for it to be CATCHed as Exception.

**What I don't understand:**
Once the user types in 5 for example, my own created exception catches it - What I don't understand is how to tell my created Exception Class what to catch, what to look for? Where do I type these numbers in my Exception and tell my Exception class that those numbers are exceptions?

If I wasn't clear enough, please let me know, I will try to rephrase myself.

Comment: Exceptions don't actively look for violations. You may be looking for some form of validation framework.

Comment: Can you show a small sample of your code?

Comment: I think you misunderstand what an exception is used for. An exception should indicate something has gone wrong, which is why it crashes your program! You'll need the `if / else` no matter what.

Comment: yes you need validation. exceptions are different

Comment: I think you are using the name *Exception* in a completely invalid way. Exceptions are *thrown* and *being caught*. They don't *catch* anything. An Exception basically is a simple data holder object that explains in detail why it has been thrown.

Comment: It seems I did misunderstood however - for example how "ArgumentException" was created? Some how it knows that null is exception, so I'm assuming it was toled within "ArgumentException" that null is Exception. Or "ArgumentOutOfRangeException" or "FormatException"  - they all know that this or that is defined as exception and I'm wondering if you can make your own Exception so that it will consider numbers from 5-9 as Exception, as error.

Comment: I have took some time to figure this out and all of your answers helped me a lot! So great thank you to all of you, I'm often coming back to learn from your answers and in different ways things can be solved - thanks every one again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exceptions don't just happen. When your code throws an exception, for example if you try to divide by 0 and you get a `DivideByZeroException` - it means that some code somewhere has to have a line like `throw new DivideByZeroException();`  . (Admittedly, this is a simplification of the matter.)

So in order to throw the exception you want - you have to test the input and if it's not good then throw an exception.

And assuming you don’t mean that you need a custom Exception (e.g. `FiveToNineException`) - you can just use this:

```
if (i >= 5 && i <= 9)
{
    throw new Exception("5 to 9 Exception");
}
```

Or:

```
if (i >= 5 && i <= 9)
{
    Exception e = new Exception("5 to 9 Exception");
    e.Data.Add("The number ", i);
    throw e;
}
```

**EDIT**

For a very simple custom exception:

```
public class FiveToNineException : System.Exception
{
    public FiveToNineException() : base() { }
}
```

and then you can have:

```
throw new FiveToNineException();
```

And:

```
try {/*Do something*/ }
catch (FiveToNineException ex) { }
```

For more information see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17137743/939213) for an answer to a question of mine.

Comment: Well it's kinda what I was looking for to create my custom Exception :) for the sake of the example let it be named "FiveToNineException" so that I can use it with CATCH (FiveToNineException). Any way of doing it? Or link to how this can be done? Thx for paying attention to my problem.

Answer (score 2):

You may benefit from an Exception [tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20191217032656/http://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/CSharp/Lesson15).

It sounds like you are trying to do three things.

1 Read a number from a text input field.

2 Determine whether that is a valid number.

3 If the number is invalid, throw an exception.

```
//Read input
int i = -1;
i = int.TryParse(MyTextField.Text, out i);

if (i >= 5 && i <= 9) 
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value", "Value cannot be  between 5 - 9.");
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correct I think you should try something like:

```
if (yourNumber >= 5 && yourNumber <= 9)
{
    throw new YourException(..);
}
```

**But also see the comments.** Your understanding of exceptions isn't correct.

Answer (score 1):

The below code shows the basic example of a CustomException

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            int x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            if (x >= 5 && x <= 9)
            {
                CustomException e = new CustomException("Please Eneter Another Number");
                throw e;
            }
        }

        catch (CustomException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}

public class CustomException : System.Exception
{
    public CustomException(string txt)
        : base(txt)
    {
    }
}
```